# How to apply VisualStudio 11 theme to my MFC application?

Tags: mfc

The new VS 11 features a grey-style user interface that is cool. Is it possible for me apply this to my MFC App? Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so. VS is mostly written using WPF now, so I assume this is a WPF theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last "update" for MFC controls and their appearance was the MFC Feature Pack, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982354.aspx

Unfortunately, it does not include the VS 2011 style, but maybe you find something else which would be interesting for your application (for example ribbons etc).

They did not include pictures of their controls, you can only check them in their sample application, which you can download here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983962.aspx

or via Google Image Search

http://www.google.com/search?q=mfc+feature+pack